# Prevent ajax requests to a PHP file using Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, ajax, security

I have a website called "example.com". I have a PHP file on example.com that I make .ajax() requests to. I want to prevent other sites from making requests to this file. I'm setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin in this PHP file to do so. Here is my code

```
<?php

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com', false);

    if(isset($_POST["request"]){

        echo "Request Successful";

    }

?>
```

Can this approach be exploited? Is setting this header preventing other sites from making ajax requests to the PHP file? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: Other sites can't make ajax requests to your domain by default - this is the standard single origin policy all browsers respect. You need to use the CORS headers if you want to _enable_ cross origin requests.

Comment: Thanks Preston, good to know. So to confirm, I don't need to add any extra security features to prevent other websites from making ajax requests to my PHP file?

Comment: Right, they're blocked by default.

Comment: Why don't you simply test it? Write a bit of JS code and run it on your localhost. Try to access the functionality. See in web console if it succeeds.

Comment: @PatPistachio To be clear, single origin policy is a _client side_ security feature of browsers - no modern browser, by default, will allow a script loaded from site A to issue a request to site B unless site B presents the correct CORS headers. That said, this does _not_ protect site B from malicious intent. If your goal is to ensure your _server_ doesn't respond to unexpected requests, you need an appropriate authorization scheme in place for the API.